# stuck building a 'cart management' system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a database for video spots. The main page is a list of spots and you can check them and modify them. What i want to do is build a cart system, where the checked spots' id's are automatically added to the cart and stored as a cookie. That way the use can browse multiple pages while still having everything stay checked.

So far, I have a checkbox on every spot that when checked calls a function that adds the id of the checkbox to an array and stores it as a cookie.

I'm able to retrieve the cookie through jquery. What I need to do is while looping through the spots and printing them, is to check if that spot id is in the cookie, so I can set it as checked or not through php. Is this possible? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here is what i have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var checkedItems = [];

    $('.spotCheck').click(function(){
        var currentID = this.id;
        checkedItems.push(currentID);
        updateCookie();
    });


    function updateCookie(){
        $.cookie('itemList',checkedItems);
    }


    $('#mainContainer').click(function(){
        $('#textInCenter').html($.cookie('itemList') );
    });

});
```

Clicking the checkbox adds the ID to the array checkedItems, and click the mainContainer makes it visible so I can see which items are currently in the array. I can browse through pages and the cookies stay in the array (there's no way to remove them now but I'm not worried about that right now).

So how can I check the array to see if an id is in there when I print the list of spots?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can iterate over the array with `$.filter` or `checkedItems.forEach` and just check if you get a match.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what you are stuck on, but if you are just needing to figure out if a value exists in an array, use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: but how do i reflect that in the PHP? I can use indexOf in javascript, but then how would i go about checking the proper box (the one with the matching id)?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly...You are looking to check the cookie for a value and if you find it, send it to the server to update?

Comment: I have an array of IDs set as a cookie. I want to loop through that, and for each ID, check the current page for corresponding IDs, and check the checkbox with that ID.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're looking for I think that this would work for you:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++)
{
    var elm = $('#' + checkedItems[i]);
    if (elm.length > 0)
    {
        //element with the id exists.
        elm.attr('checked', true);
    }
 }
```